# Optimization problem on trace of complex matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, global-optimization, matrix-equations

Given a complex rectangular matrix $A$ $(k \times n)$, I am interested in solving the following optimization problem over $(k\times n)$ complex matrices $x$:
$$
\mathrm{arg}\max_X \,\mathrm{trace}(X^HA).
$$

Comment: If there are no conditions on $X$ then this problem is unbounded, just replace $X$ by $\alpha X$ for $\alpha > 1$. Moreover, your objective need not be real-valued at the moment, e.g., take $X= i A$.